# How to send png file created by Matplotlib to Telegram bot

Tags: python, matplotlib, telegram-bot

When calling the / 'show_previous_week' command I want to generate a graph and send it in a message
I tried to generate a graph based on data not from a table and everything worked, but it doesn't work to get data and send a graph to a message

Here is my code

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['show_previous_week'])
    def send_previous_values(message):


    connect = sqlite3.connect('message.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    previous_values_p = cursor.execute("SELECT message FROM weight_from ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7;")
    previous_values_p = cursor.fetchall()

    previous_values_w = []
    for i in previous_values_p:
        previous_values_w.append(float(i[0]))
    previous_values_w.reverse()

    print("show", previous_values_w)
    connect.commit()

    print("previous_values_p", previous_values_p)
    print("previous_values_w", previous_values_w)

    t = ["25.10", "26.10", "27.10", "28.10", "29.10", "30.10", "01.11"]
    s = previous_values_w

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, s)

    ax.set(xlabel='time (d)', ylabel='weight (kg)',
       title='Weight change chart for 7 days')
    ax.grid()

    fig.savefig("test.png")
    plt.show()

    file = open('/test.png', 'rb')


    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file)
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, "FILEID")
```

But I get an error

```
UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
2021-10-11 14:13:24.982 python3[56435:2115058] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should 
only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: if you run on server then don't use `show()` because server may not have `XWindows/GUI` and it can't display window with plot. Error shows also that code is run in two different threads and some modules (i.e all GUI like `tkitner`, `PyQt`, `wxPython`) has to run only in one threat.

Comment: you don't need `show()` to generate file `test.png`.  And this `show()` can make problem.

Comment: BTW: you could try to use `io.BytesIO` to save image in memory without using disk.